# Forking & modifying npm package. Src or Dist? What to do with dist?

Tags: javascript, npm

I am working on a VueJS web app. One of the modules it uses is a wrapper for a javascript library installed through npm and packaged to integrate into vuejs. It does not quite fit our needs, we need to add some functionality to it, so I want to fork it and edit it.

The repo has two folders: src and dist.

As far as I understand, src is the actual src code while dist is a minified version for distribution. Questions:

1. If I want to edit it, how do I deal with the contents of /dist ? Do I delete it?
2. Do components installed through npm use the /src/ version or the /dist/ one?
3. If I delete /dist, work on the /src code, how do I recreate /dist based on the modified /src files?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your questions, I would suggest you get a bit more familiar into your stack and how to actually [build your appication](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html).

Generally speaking the `/dist` folder contains automatically generated files, which may be uploaded to a webserver of your choice. Since you are using VueJS, you should be able to generate these files by running `npm run build`.

---

> 1. If I want to edit it, how do I deal with the contents of /dist ? Do I delete it?

As I already mentioned, these files are automatically generated by running `npm run build`. Therefore everytime you run this command, everything in `/dist`, will be automatically updated.

> 2. Do components installed through npm use the /src/ version or the /dist/ one?

Your working directory is always `/src`. Dependencies can be used like in any other application (this example uses [Axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios), which is a http client):

```js
import axios from 'axios';

const httpClient = axios.create({ baseURL: 'https://api.something.com' });
httpClient.get(/* ... */);
```

If you are a beginner and are not 100% sure about how to use depencencies, I highly encourage you to read this article: [An Absolute Beginner's Guide to Using npm](https://nodesource.com/blog/an-absolute-beginners-guide-to-using-npm/)

> 3. If I delete /dist, work on the /src code, how do I recreate /dist based on the modified /src files?

You do not have to delete anything in `/dist`. Simply running `npm run build` automatically will add the latest changes.

---

Please keep in mind that running `npm run build` is only relevant for your **production environment**. For your development environment you **always want to use a dev server**, which can be started with `npm run serve`.

Comment: I want to fork the github repo of the library and modify it. The repo on github has a /src/ folder and a /dist folder. Hence my question. It seems independent of npm.

Comment: @RogerZak if you fork the project, and the project is based on Vue, it should be the same. Running `npm run build` should automatically generate the contents inside of `/dist`. But then again, this information may be wrong, as I do not have any insight in the repository itself. Maybe there is some information on installing in the README of the authors repository. Alternatively you may want to also check the `package.json`, which defines all the available scripts in the "scripts" section.

Comment: Thank you. So if I get you right, I only have to worry about /src/. When Im done with the edits, in my main project, I run npm install (with my modified package as the source) and it will generate dist.